# Arch Linux - Boot stucked after installing SDDM on amd laptop

Tags: linux, arch-linux, kde

newbie here, after installing SDDM booting is stuck at: Starting version 245.7-1-arch.When i boot without quiet parameter it's stuck on Finished| Load/Save random seed.

When i boot with loglevel=7 no errors show after Load/Save random seed line.

I tried - reinstalling sddm, plasma. Installing rng-tools, haveged

UPDATE: Running sddm-greeter returns: GREETER: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found

UPDATE 2: Just tried GDM and it doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

FIXED: Changed Linux-LTS kernel to Linux